# How plot a line with different colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have created a strategy where I have a `dataFrame` (pandas) which represents a `time series` (x is a `date` and y is a `number`). I also have an array of classes that classify each point of this time series. I would like to know how can I plot a line (or points - scatter) in matplotlib considering the color of each point using my array of classes. For sample:

My dataframe

```
print(df)

date          value
2018-07-04    1.25
2018-07-05    2.15
2018-07-06    1.75
2018-07-07    1.95
...


print(classes)
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, ... ]
```

I have tried using the [DataFrame.plot.line](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.line.html) but it is limited to a single color. How can I customize it (it could be a scatter) to plot something like the image bellow?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/color_by_yvalue.html#sphx-glr-gallery-color-color-by-yvalue-py

Answer (score 1):

The usual idea is to mesh the plot into fine-grain lines/points then plot. For scatter:

```
import seaborn as sns

df['class'] = classes

s = df.set_index(['date']).asfreq('T');
s['value'] = s['value'].interpolate()
s['class'] = s['class'].ffill().astype(int).astype('category')
s = s.reset_index()


sns.scatterplot(x='date',y='value',hue='class', data=s)
```

For line plot, [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) could be helpful.

Comment: Hi Quang, thank you the post. Let me ask, what is the `sns` object?

Comment: It's [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/), pretty handy for plotting long-form data.